# Rails 4 - Two models setup for one to many association but cannot pull all the records associated with one model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, associations

I have 2 models: Doc and Row.
Doc has many Rows and a Row belongs_to a single Doc.

Here is what the models look like in code:

```
Doc:
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: docs
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#  numrows    :integer
#  user       :string(255)
#  source     :string(255)
#  size       :string(255)
#  location   :string(255)
#  status     :string(255)
#

class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rows
```

Row:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: rows
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#  numCols    :integer
#  type       :string(255)
#  content    :text
#  status     :string(255)
#  doc_id     :integer
#

class Row < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :doc, :foreign_key => "doc_id", :class_name => "Doc"

=begin
Status of a row can be:
1) header
2) body
3) ignore
4) nil
=end
```

Now in rails console Here are the set of commands Im running:

```
2.0.0-p247 :084 > @doc = Doc.find(9)
  Doc Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `docs`.* FROM `docs` WHERE `docs`.`id` = 9 LIMIT 1
 => #<Doc id: 9, created_at: "2014-07-14 16:42:54", updated_at: "2014-07-14 16:42:59", numrows: 761, user: "XXXX", source: nil, size: nil, location: "ABC.csv", status: "parsing_complete">


2.0.0-p247 :085 > @doc.rows
NoMethodError: undefined method `rows' for #<Doc:0x007ff20c1b8860>
    from /Users/XXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:439:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/XXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:155:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):85
    from /Users/XXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/XXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2.0.0-p247 :086 >


2.0.0-p247 :086 > Row.where(:doc_id => 9)
  Row Load (31.7ms)  SELECT `rows`.* FROM `rows` WHERE `rows`.`doc_id` = 9
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Row id: 1, created_at: "2014-07-14 16:42:57", updated_at: "2014-07-14 16:42:57", numCols: nil, type: nil, content: "[PROGRAMS] (All Locations|Consolidated),,,,,,,,,,,,...">,
```

## ,

....

So the Row objects exist. However, Im not able to pull them up through the corresponding Doc model object.

Since Ive set up all the association. I'm wondering what trick am I not getting here

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in Rails 4 due to strong params its not enough to set up the model relationships. One also has to permit the retrieval of the associated model by setting up the "model_params" method accordingly.

Here, I changed my docs_controller/doc_params to the following

```
     # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def doc_params
          params.require(:doc).permit(:status, :user, :numrows, :size, :source, :location, :row_ids => [])
        end
```

Notice "row_ids => []". Thats what was missing. Now everything is fine.